# Why error for one user

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

My Xpages application is showing a strange problem.  I have an XPage with with a tab control (2 tabs) and each tab has a dynamicviewpanel and a delete button.  Each tab shows a different view depending on a condition.  The first tab works completely fine for both myself and the user but the second tab, the view shows the correct documents and the delete button works fine for me and a fellow developer but when the user clicks on the delete button in the second tab they receive the error.

```
<xp:button id="DeleteContract" value="Delete Contract ID">
 <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
    refreshMode="complete">
  <xp:this.action>
   <xp:actionGroup>
     <xp:confirm
         message="Are you sure?">
     </xp:confirm>
     <![CDATA[#{javascript:var viewPanel=getComponent 
          ("dynamicViewPanel3");
       var docIDArray=viewPanel.getSelectedIds();
       for(i=0; i < docIDArray.length; i++){
         var docId=docIDArray[i];
         var doc=database.getDocumentByID(docId);
         doc.remove(true);
      }}]]>
    </xp:actionGroup>
   </xp:this.action>
 </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

The error being presented on the browser is "Exception occurred calling method NotesDocument.remove(boolean) null"

The logs do not tell me much either

All the permissions are the same for each tab etc so it shouldn't be a permissions issue.  Why would this be occurring?

Comment: To get more infos you can surround your code with a try-catch(e) block and print out the exception.

Comment: looks that your `doc` variable is null, and when you call `doc.remove(true)` you get the exception.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Thanks for response.  I understand but why does it not throw this error when I run it?  It only does this for a certain user??

Comment: Does the user have delete access in the ACL?

Comment: @AJF a possible reason - this user does not have access to this document. And this document is not visible for him.

Comment: @SteveZavocki The user can delete documents in the other tab with no issues!!

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Thanks again.  The user can use the applications general search bar and locate the document and open and amend it there.  This is happening for several documents

Comment: @AJF in this case try the following steps. 1. Rebuild database view indexes. Open the database and press `Ctrl+Shift+F9` combination on the keyboard. Then try to execute your code. If the problem persists, then do the following: 2. Run Domino Administrator, find the database you are working on, select it, open context menu (right mouse click) and select "Fixup". Please check these steps and tell me about the results.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov  Thanks Rafael.  I will do but first have to try and reload the data into the database from a backup as have deleted all the relevant documents trying to replicate the users problem.  I managed to get something out of an xml formatted error log named error-log-0.xml located in D:/Notes/data/domino/workspace/logs.  It states - Notes error: You are not authorized to perform that operation&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at lotus.domino.local.Document.remove(Unknown Source)

Comment: @RafaelOsipov I have tried the two fixes you suggested but the result for the user is the same.  I confirmed they can find the document using the ID in the general search bar and then open the document.  Also enter the document ID in a search facility in the second tab and find the document.  Its when they check the document check box in the second tab and click the delete button. But the strange thing is the user can check a document check box in the first tab and click delete and it works.  Sounds very strange to me!!

Comment: @AJF seems that something is wrong with the database internals. I would make a copy of the database **via Notes client** and check this issue for copied database.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Thanks again for response.  I have created a workaround instead as my manager will not allow any more time spent on this.  What do you mean though "copied database"?  Thanks again for assistance

Comment: @AJF On my experience when a database becomes corrupt and fixup does not work as expected, then I copy this database using Notes client. Copying a database via notes client recreates it from the scratch, and new copied database works properly. This approach solved many issues related to misterious documetns, which are visible, but cannot be get via script (broken view indexes), documents invisible from (`SELECT @ALL`) view, became visible when database was copied. And so on. In my previous comment I advised to copy the problem database via notes client, and run your script into copied database

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Wow!!  Hold on! I have just discovered the user was not  giving me correct feedback.  The user cannot delete on EITHER of the tabbed pages - while I incorrectly thought the user could delete on one tab but not the other.  Does this shed light on the issue please?.  The user gets the same error when they click on the delet button on either tab!!

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Am I being completely stupid here then.  Is it a case of just ensuring the have deletion privaliges in the ACL???!!!

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Just discovered certain users part of different group in ACL (Design was not down to me) and this group has no Delete permission.  I suppose this answers the question

Comment: @AJF when you open ACL dialog, there's a button "Effective access". http://imgur.com/oL2KszG   Click on this button and examine effective access of the problem user. Make sure he/she has permission to delete documents or whatever is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the logic in the solution was working after all.  It was bad feedback that was making us think the specific user could delete in one tab but not the other.  After discovering the user could not delete from any tab, we found that they were a member of another lotus notes group that we could assign deletion privileges to and then all was working for them.  Stupid I know, but it was confusing feedback that made me assume the user could delete in one tab but not the other.  Thanks to all who contributed